# Intellij custom syntax support inside PHP language

Tags: parsing, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I would like to develop support for own grammar inside another language in Intellij/PhpStorm. specifically, I would like to parse some part of PHPDOC comment by my parser. Is it possible to plug-in my parser into another (php) parser?

I have already written my parser & grammar, but I would like to make it work without own file extension.

If it's not possible, is there some way to modify behavior of PHP parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you can do in this area is register parsers for additional PhpDoc tags which are not supported by PhpStorm out of the box. There is no possibility to replace the entire PhpDoc parser with your own parser.

Comment: Please, could you point to any source about "registering parsers for additional PhpDoc tags"? Thanks!

Comment: I can't point you to any source because the PHP plugin is not open-source, but I can tell you that you need to create a class extending PhpDocTagParser and pass it to PhpDocTagParserRegistry.register().

Comment: Thank you a lot, I am not, currently, sure if it solves my issue, but at least you mentioned the only way which may help. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @yole Is it possible to write a plugin that makes overriding of syntax checking of java to a custom one .?